# How to set up a server to receive all GPS hardware information?

Tags: javascript

Server set up to receive all information from GPS hardware;
But it only receives the IMEI of the device.
Sending information from the hardware is based on the AVL Packet.
What script or code should be written to get the rest of the information from the device, such as time and location?

Comment: Does the "device" come with a manual?

Comment: Yes, but exact information is not available

Comment: I dont know the name nor model of the device.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all specially @GetSet. I checked and found the following manual and find the data structure and fixed my problem.
I am posting it below so if anyone needs it can read:

[Link to FMB920 Teltonika Wiki](https://wiki.teltonika-gps.com/view/Teltonika_Data_Sending_Protocols#Introduction)

I needed to send back a code representing the data I needed so the device would sent back the info.
For example I need to send back 01 as byte from the TCP tunnel that the device created to get back the GSP data.

Comment: you can use nodejs parser library for parsing data. please have a look here [link]https://www.npmjs.com/package/complete-teltonika-parser